# Populate a table programmatically with an mpp file in ADF?

Tags: java, oracle-adf, mpxj

I've been trying to fill an ADF file with an .MPP extension file. I was able to print the data in console but I could not pass it to the af - table. I use the InputFile component and I put its ValueChangeListener, in its method is where I command to call the other methods that do the reading of the file, I tried to fill with an ArrayList.

Has anyone filled a table with such files? Or the contrary could make some suggestions.?

I leave the image of the reading of the file.

This class reads the file

```
public void listHierarchy(ProjectFile file) {

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm z");

    for (Task task : file.getChildTasks()) {
        System.out.println("Task: " + task.getName());

        Date date = task.getStart();

        String startDate =
            date != null ? df.format(date) : "(no hay fecha de inicio)";
        date = task.getFinish();

        String finishDate =
            date != null ? df.format(date) : "(no hay fecha final)";

        Double porcentaje =
            Double.parseDouble(task.getPercentageComplete().toString());

        personList.add(new llenarActividad(task.getName(), porcentaje,
                                           task.getDuration().toString(),
                                           startDate, finishDate, "mono"));
        listHierarchy(task, " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" s/* e definen las tareas en formato jerarquico */");
    System.out.println();

}

/**
 * @param task 
 * @param indent
 */

public void listHierarchy(Task task, String indent) {

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm z");

    for (Task child : task.getChildTasks()) {

        Date date = task.getStart();

        String startDate =
            date != null ? df.format(date) : "(no hay fecha de inicio)";
        date = task.getFinish();

        String finishDate =
            date != null ? df.format(date) : "(no hay fecha final)";

        Double porcentaje =
            Double.parseDouble(task.getPercentageComplete().toString());

        System.out.println(indent + "Task: " + child.getName() +
                           task.getPercentageComplete() +
                           task.getDuration() + startDate + finishDate);
        personList.add(new llenarActividad(child.getName(), porcentaje,
                                           task.getDuration().toString(),
                                           startDate, finishDate, "mono"));
        listHierarchy(child, indent + " ");
    }
}
```

and this class upload File

```
public class llenarActividadBean {


    public void cargarArchivo(ValueChangeEvent vce) throws Exception {

        ProjectHelper ph = new ProjectHelper();

        if (vce.getNewValue() == null) {
        } else {

            UploadedFile file = (UploadedFile)vce.getNewValue();
            //Se asigna el archivo a la variable path

            String path = ph.uploadFile(file);

            //Se obtiene el Objeto de vce
            ProjectReader reader = ProjectReaderUtility.getProjectReader(path);

            //Se hace la lectura del archivo
            ProjectFile mpx = reader.read(path);

            System.out.println("MPP file type: " + mpx.getMppFileType());

            ph.listAssignments(mpx);

            ph.listHierarchy(mpx);

        }
    }
}
```

[image: view Of Upload File]

Comment: @Marvin this is my code

Comment: I assume `personList` is the input to your ADF table? Can you show how you are setting up this relationship?

Comment: @JonIles sure...  <af:table value="#{ProjectHelper.personList}" var="row"
                            rowBandingInterval="0" id="t1">

Comment: You could also create a programmatic View Object and add it to your page from the Datacontrol as you do with any normal VO. Then is just matter of walk your file and insert new rows on that VO. I find this way is easier to implement.